# Javascript array always returns empty array in iOS9 beta

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, ios9

I have a very weird issue happening in iOS9 beta 5 - arrays seem to be empty even when elements have been added.

Sounds crazy but here's what it looks like in Safari iOS9 - this is just on the google homepage, no plugins - just vanilla webkit/javascript:

[image]

Whereas on Safari desktop, I see the correct behaviour:

[image]

Is anyone else having this issue?

Here's the code to reproduce:

```
myArray = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']  
console.log(myArray.length)  
console.log(myArray)  
console.log(myArray.slice(0,1))  
console.log(myArray.indexOf('fish'))
```

Thanks!

Comment: So is the issue with the array or the console?

Comment: what do you get with `myArray.join('')` ?

Comment: @RobG it *could* be the console - but the only reason I checked is because of a bug in an app that could be caused by this behaviour.

Comment: @Tom ah - it does actually return the correct elements...

Comment: @StephenBartholomew—there is no specification for what the console should do, but certainly what it seems to be doing isn't very helpful. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be caused by the implementation of `toString`, that `console.log` is calling, rather than an empty array.

Comment: This certainly seems the most likely - it must be a red herring that it also perfectly explains the bug I'm seeing.

I'll take this as correct and keep looking - if arrays really did act like this I guess I'd see way more issues!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Safari 8 to inspect iOS 9. You should be using Safari 9 or later to inspect iOS 9. Safari 9 is available on El Capitan, Yosemite, and Mavericks.

You may also use a [WebKit Nightly](http://nightly.webkit.org) on Yosemite and Mavericks to get equivalent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the console.
You can see the value to debug using alert if you need to.

eg: `alert(['cat', 'dog'])`. It will pop up the result you need.

I had a similar issue when I was using `replaceAll` method. It does not have support in ios/safari 12. If you are facing this probably you can have issues with some functions like the replaceAll. For my case I had to use a **polyfill**.